# Hosting web api and mvc app on Appharbor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, appharbor

Before I redesign my application I want to know if this is possible:

- Using MVC 6 have a web app call a Web API in the same project.
- Deploy both on AppHarbor.
- Let an external service application call the WebAPI's functions.

  1. Will this work?
  2. Will I have to upgrade from Canoe?
  3. Can the Web App and the Web API use the same MSSQL DB?

Comment: Everything should work as you expect. I don't know if AppHarbor supports MVC 6 though. I don't think you need to upgrade as you have one Project. And with this one project you can use the same MSSQL DB for sure.

Comment: If the web apps url will be something.apphb.com - what would the Web API's be (the URL from which I access its functions externally)?

Comment: something.apphb.com/api/... I think